# Magento 2 Mega menu

Tags: megamenu

I need to make my site menu like this [porto mega menu](https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo5_en). Can anyone please suggest a free extension for mega menu in magento 2

Comment: Try any of this https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-mega-menu-extension.html

Comment: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/free-magento-2-easy-megamenu

Comment: Try this one REF: http://store.ibnab.com/free-magento-2-easy-megamenu.html

Comment: i will tried and update you @rakesh

Comment: I will tried and update u @prathap

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked "Free extension" for mega menu, but I've noticed that both bsscommerce and ibnab .(For free, It may not be a bad idea to just write custom your own)

Comment: Thank you @rightnowtoday